# Do you put GPA in a CV?

Tags: cv, gpa

I have had bad luck in the past, but things are turning around... I am applying for internships for my current Masters program. Do I put my GPA under all previous schools attended? Do I need to list all schools attended? My undergraduate GPA was strong. I did a post-bac program, which turned out to be a scam, and the school was shut down. My GPA there was not good. I then attended a professional school where I was injured by a professor, so I left the school. My GPA there was decent. What do you recommend? My current GPA for my Masters is really strong.

Comment: Has the internship site requested transcripts in addition to your CV? If so, you won't need to include your GPAs from the accredited programs. If they're just asking for a CV, you should indicate your GPA from each institute, excluding the non-accredited one.

Comment: Do not put your GPA in your CV. If they need it, they will ask for it through transcripts or through their application.